# Go postgres prepared statement with interval parameter not working

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to simply insert the following into the postgres database by using Go's pq library (I'm following Let's Go book, but using Postgres instead of mySQL):

```
title := "O snail"
content := "O snail\nClimb Mount Fuji,\nBut slowly, slowly!\n\n - Kobayashi"
expires := "7"

stmt := `INSERT INTO snippets (title, content, created, expires)
    VALUES($1, $2, current_timestamp, current_timestamp + interval '$3 days')`

_, err := m.DB.Exec(stmt, title, content, expires)
```

But this throws an error:
`handlers.go:56: pq: got 3 parameters but the statement requires 2`

In fact, if I just remove `expires` from the last line, and pass in 2 parameters, it works, and the the interval value gets treated as '3 days'.

How does this make any sense? Why is `$` ignored? I thought it's due to some escaping stuff with single quotes, so I tried `'\$3 days'`, but it gives an error `pq: syntax error at or near "\"`. I also get an error if I try to escape single quotes `\'$3 days\'`. Any suggestions?

Comment: *"Why is $ ignored?"* -- because it's inside a string literal. That means the "$N" is treated literally as part of the string and not as a placeholder for arguments. You can't have $N parameters in string literals. It's simply not possible. Escaping won't help you. Instead you should concatenate the paremter with the string. Or construct the full interval in Go and pass the whole value to the query. Concat: `($3 || ' days')`. Or, full interval constructed in Go: `expires := "7 days"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also cast the parameter to `interval` and pass the complete interval string as the query argument:

```
expires := "7 days"

stmt := `INSERT INTO snippets (title, content, created, expires)
    VALUES($1, $2, current_timestamp, current_timestamp + $3::interval)`

_, err := m.DB.Exec(stmt, title, content, expires)
```

This also gives you more control about how you determine the value of `expire`, for example with `fmt.Sprintf`, or string concatenation, in case you want to have also the unit of time as an externally supplied argument.

Answer (score 7):

You may multiply `interval '1 day'` by a bound parameter, to achieve the correct interval you want.

```
stmt := `INSERT INTO snippets (title, content, created, expires)
VALUES($1, $2, current_timestamp, current_timestamp + interval '1 day' * $3)`
```